# Wordpress rewriting URL of a page

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I'm currently creating a new Wordpress from scratch for a client who already has a website with a good SEO, and I have a question.
I would like to use the former url for the new pages in wordpress, in order to keep the SEO, instead of the 301 redirection. 
For example I have the following page on the old site `http://my-exemple.com/en/contact.php` and on my wordpress I have : `http://my-exemple.com/en/contact-php/`

The dot is replaced by a `-` and there is a `/` at the end. How could I have the exact same url on wordpress ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should simply edit the pages to `/contact` instead of `contact.php`.

With Wordpress, `contact.php` will look for a specific php file by that name. 301 redirecting the `.php` URL's to their non `.php` counterparts will not cause any harm to your SEO performance.

That said, if you really wanted to rewrite URLs to include the `.php` at the end, you could do this using the `$wp_rewrite` object in Wordpress.

It would look like this:
`$wp_rewrite-> page_structure = $wp_rewrite-> page_structure . '.php';`

[Class Reference/WP Rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)